# Spring RabbitMQ Messaging. Using JSON send efficiently

Tags: java, json, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, message-listener

If using JSON Object to send and receive over RabbitMQ is this the cleanest way to send and receive? All that conversion seems inefficient.

**Sending Code**

```
JSONObject messageJSON = new JSONObject();
messageJSON.put("messageId", "testId");
messageJSON.put("NodeId", "testNode");

template.convertAndSend("TEST-EXCHANGE",
    "routing.test", messageJSON.toJSONString()
        .getBytes());
```

**Receive Code**

```
public class Listener implements MessageListener {

  @Override
  public void onMessage(Message message) {
    String recmessage = new String(message.getBody());
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(recmessage);
    System.out
        .println("Message Received  " + (String) obj.get("messageId"));
  }
}
```

**Solution From Answer given**

You need to add the Dependency of Jackson. Below is maven:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Add to the Spring Config**

```
<bean id="amqpCorrectionTemplate" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="messageConverter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter">
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Add to the message Listener**

```
Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jmc = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
JSONObject obj  = (JSONObject) jmc.fromMessage(message);
```

**Sending Code**
Only send the JSON Object passed in.

```
template.convertAndSend("TEST-EXCHANGE",
    "routing.test", messageJSON);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wrong question: the AMQP protocol (as any other wire-based) gets deal just with bytes, so it's up to your application how to convert to `byte[]` and back (if it is Java everywhere, of course).

From other side it would be better to your configuration based on the out-of-the- box converters. For example `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter`.

See more information in the [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#message-converters).

Comment: This is the solution for future viewers, and also @Artem if most efficient. Putting the solution in the question.